# Android App OpenFeint Problem

Tags: android, openfeint

I've Integrated OpenFeint in my android game,
but it loads automatically and ask for enalble or disable openfeint when the game starts. If Internet connection is slow, then openfeint takes too long to respond.

How can i stop openfeint loading automatically and ask user to use it or not using code.?

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

Option 1: instead of **OpenFeint.initialise**, use **OpenFeint.initializeWithoutLoggingIn**, then display a prompt to the user. If they click "yes", call OpenFeint.login().

Option 2: Don't call initialize until the user clicks "yes". This mean more code changes (moving from your Application class' **onCreate()**) but will give you better performance, because initializing OpenFeint can be quite slow.

Comment: If they don't have "enable account retreival" then they'll have to do this every time. You could store if they ever log into OF then always do the .login(), but that might get annoying.